# array.select not iterating through every element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails controller and this code only loop through the first element in the `metrics` array? Why is that?

```
# /metrics/:id
def values
  @metric = metrics.select do |metric|
    id = metric['href'].split('/').last
    p "id == params[:id] = #{id == params[:id]}" # false on the first iteration (but never gets to the next iteration
    return id == params[:id]
  end
  p "HERE?" # We never get here!
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `return` statement from your method, Ruby uses implicit return (see https://jtrudell.github.io/blog/ruby_return_values/), so the result of a `block` is the last line that is evaluated in that block, the return statement in your code is treated as a `return` from the `values` method. Your method needs to look something like:

```
def values
  @metric = metrics.select do |metric|
    metric['href'].split('/').last == params[:id]
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh i thought for every implicit return you could have an explicit return. Guess not.

Comment: @Catfish Every implicit return from a method or lambda, not blocks though.

Comment: @Catfish `next` is to blocks what `return` is to methods.